# C++ edit distance / string similarity function based on the Jaro-Winkler algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, strings, c++17, edit-distance

I wrote a short library function, based on an example from [Rosetta](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Jaro_distance#C.2B.2B), to compare two strings and determine similarity, using [Jaro-Winkler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance).

A short copy-paste ready example:

### main.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "jaro_winkler.hpp"

int main() {
    std::string a { "DWAYNE" };
    std::string b { "DUANE" };

    std::cout << "Similarity for '" << a
              << "' and '" << b
              << "': " << edit_distance::jaro_winkler(a, b)
              << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Similarity for 'MARTHA' and 'MARHTA': "
              << edit_distance::jaro_winkler("MARTHA", "MARHTA")
              << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Similarity for 'DIXON' and 'DICKSONX': "
              << edit_distance::jaro_winkler("DIXON", "DICKSONX")
              << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Similarity for 'JELLYFISH' and 'SMELLYFISH': "
              << edit_distance::jaro_winkler("JELLYFISH", "SMELLYFISH")
              << std::endl;
}
```

### jaro_winkler.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string_view>

namespace edit_distance {
    template <typename T = float>
    inline T jaro(const std::string_view source,
                  const std::string_view target)
    {
        const unsigned sl = source.length();
        const unsigned tl = target.length();

        if (sl == 0 || tl == 0) return 0;

        const auto match_distance = (sl == 1 && tl == 1)
                                        ? 0
                                        : (std::max(sl, tl) / 2 - 1);
        auto source_matches = new bool[sl] {0};
        auto target_matches = new bool[tl] {0};
        unsigned matches = 0;
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < sl; ++i) {
            const auto end = std::min(i + match_distance + 1, tl);
            for (auto k = i > match_distance ? (i - match_distance) : 0u; k < end; ++k)
            {
                if (!target_matches[k] && source[i] == target[k]) {
                    source_matches[i] = true;
                    target_matches[k] = true;
                    ++matches;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (matches == 0) {
            delete[] source_matches;
            delete[] target_matches;
            return 0;
        }

        T t = 0.0;
        unsigned k = 0;
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < sl; ++i) {
            if (source_matches[i]) {
                while (!target_matches[k]) ++k;
                if (source[i] != target[k]) t += 0.5;
                ++k;
            }
        }

        const T m = matches;
        delete[] source_matches;
        delete[] target_matches;
        return (m / sl + m / tl + (m - t) / m) / 3.0;
    }

    template <typename T = float>
    inline T jaro_winkler(const std::string_view source,
                          const std::string_view target,
                          const unsigned prefix = 2,
                          const T boost_treshold = 0.7,
                          const T scaling_factor = 0.1)
    {
        const auto similarity = jaro<T>(source, target);

        if (similarity > boost_treshold) {
            int common_prefix = 0;
            const int l = std::min((unsigned)std::min(source.length(), target.length()), prefix);
            for (; common_prefix < l; ++common_prefix) {
                if (source[common_prefix] != target[common_prefix]) break;
            }
            return similarity + scaling_factor * common_prefix * (1 - similarity);
        } else {
            return similarity;
        }
    }
} // namespace edit_distance
```

I'd be happy to hear any comments or critiques.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things that I immediately see in this code that have room for improvement:

```
template <typename T = float>
```

Assuming you only want floating point values passed as template parameters (Since you do floating point arithmetic later on), you could add:

```
static_assert(std::is_floating_point<T>::value, 
              "jaro can only be used with floating point types");
```

---

```
const unsigned sl = source.length();
const unsigned tl = target.length();
```

While the above may work for your code, the type for the length of the `std::string_view` isn't always guaranteed to be a plain `unsigned int`. Consider using [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) as the variable type, or `std::string_view::size_type`.

---

```
auto source_matches = new bool[sl] {0};
auto target_matches = new bool[tl] {0};
```

1. The use of `auto` is confusing here. It is hard to tell *at first glance* that you are meaning to use a dynamic array. `auto` doesn't shorten the type much either, so you may want to remove it.
2. Raw dynamic arrays are a large source of error. Consider using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. This will also allow you to remove the deletes later on in your code.

---

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < sl; ++i)
```

You could use `std::size_t` here. Don't make assumptions about `unsigned` types.

---

```
delete[] source_matches;
delete[] target_matches;
```

Using a `std::vector` would allow you to remove this.

---

```
(unsigned)std::min(source.length(), target.length())
```

If you *have* to use a cast, prefer using [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast), as it makes your intent clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your review! You are entirely correct that floating points should be enforced (through `static_assert` or `enable_if`). I think you missed the point in your second remark: the code specifies `unsigned` specifically to... store the size in an `unsigned`. If I'd use `auto` as you suggest it's whatever the platform dictates, which breaks further use of the variables (`std::min` doesn't allow mixing type sizes or signedness, leading to fragile code. About your 3rd remark: The deduction for `auto` is in the same line and reduces duplication of information, it's a style thing I guess.

Comment: About `auto` for `i`: Same remark as before, the whole goal is to be explicit, `auto` will deduce `0` to `int`. You say don't assume, but that's exactly what you're suggesting as a replacement. If you'd want to take it further you could go for `decltype(sl)`, that would be more correct and far less clear. About using a `std::vector`, this is a matter of preference. I checked and a vector is very slow by comparison, this is performance sensitive code and the scope is very clear, hence the choice for manual memory management in this specific case.

Comment: If you use `auto i`, you'll want to change its initializer to `0u`.  But as Stefan says, you really want it to match `s1`.

Comment: @Stefan, how did you compare the speed of `std::vector` against `new bool[]`?  And were you using `std::vector<bool>`, which has known problems?  (It's more compact than your array, at a cost of performance and substitutability.)  A closer equivalent would be  `std::vector<unsigned char>`.  If you really want the vector, I'd recommend `std::make_unique<bool[]>(s1)` as a safer alternative to the raw pointer.

Comment: I ran a range of types and compile flags (O0, O2, O3, Ofast) just to reconfirm earlier experiences, from `bool` to vectors of `str::string` and `unsigned` (close to a pointer in size). Tested `reserve(n)` and allocation inside and outside of loops. Closest I could get a vector is half the performance of a plain heap array. I took the `unsigned` as general case as it seemed indeed to have least issues. I'm aware that more complex functions will dwarf the difference. Interestingly `std::array` was slower as well, even though it shouldn't have been. `std::make_unique` is a good suggestion.

Comment: @Stefan, Ah, I see what you mean with your comment about unsigned types. However, there is still the risk of possibly overflow for an extremely large string (Rare, but possible, so I suggest `std::size_t`) As far as the `auto i` went, I did mean to include that you should add `0u` as well. I will edit that in. As for the vector, notice I didn't say a boolean vector. That can have numerous issues (Being a specialization), so you could probably just use a vector of unsigned chars. You could even switch to a deque, or a unique pointer as Toby said.

Answer (score 2):

## Naming

Because the namespace is called `edit_distance`, it's easy to assume that `jaro()` means Jaro *distance*, but it actually computes the Jaro *similarity*.  Similarly for `jaro_winkler()`.  It may be worth adding a suffix to disambiguate them.

## Include your own headers first

The test program includes `<string>` and `<iostream>` before `"jaro_winkler.hpp"`.  Generally, I prefer the opposite order, to avoid masking forgotten includes in my own headers.

## Refactor the tests

There's a lot of repetition in the tests, which can be reduced:

```
static void show_distance(std::string_view a, std::string_view b)
{
    std::cout << "Similarity for '" << a
              << "' and '" << b
              << "': " << edit_distance::jaro_winkler_similarity(a, b)
              << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    show_distance(std::string{"DWAYNE"}, "DUANE");
    show_distance("MARTHA", "MARHTA");
    show_distance("DIXON", "DICKSONX");
    show_distance("JELLYFISH", "SMELLYFISH");
}
```

## Default to `double`

In C and C++, `double` is the default floating-point type; `float` and `long double` have to be specifically requested.  It's best to stay consistent with this, so I would write `template <typename T = double>`.

You can use SFINAE to prevent non-floating-point types from being seen:

```
template <typename T = double>
inline std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, T>
jaro_similarity(const std::string_view source, const std::string_view target)
```

## What if both strings are empty?

I'd argue that two equal strings must always have a similarity of one, even if they are both empty.  So I'd re-write that test:

```
    if (source == target)
        return 1;
    if (source.empty() || target.empty())
        return 0;
```

I think `source.empty()` indicates the intent slightly better than `sl == 0`, but that might be just me.

## Simplify a test

```
    const auto match_distance = (sl == 1 && tl == 1)
                                    ? 0
                                    : (std::max(sl, tl) / 2 - 1);
```

Since we're using `std::max(sl, tl)` in one branch (and since `std::max()` is declared `constexpr`), it may be cheaper/clearer to use it for the test, too:

```
    const auto match_distance = std::max(sl, tl) < 2
                                ? 0
                                : std::max(sl, tl) / 2 - 1;
```

## Avoid raw pointers

Instead of creating `new bool[]`, we normally prefer objects that C++ will clean up for us.  The usual approach is to create a `std::vector`, but when the type is `bool`, that selects the (non-Standard-Container) specialization, which we don't want, for reasons of speed.  We could use a `std::vector<char>` (or `<unsigned char>`), or we could stick with a `bool[]` but ask a smart pointer to manage it:

```
    auto source_matches = std::make_unique<bool[]>(sl);
    auto target_matches = std::make_unique<bool[]>(tl);
```

## Prefer `std::size_t` over `unsigned int` for indexes

The standard size type is guaranteed to have enough range for even the longest array.

## Count using an integer type

Instead of accumulating `0.5` at a time, we can accumulate by 1 at a time, and divide at the end:

```
    std::size_t t = 0;
    std::size_t k = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0;  i < sl;  ++i) {
        if (source_matches[i]) {
            while (!target_matches[k]) ++k;
            if (source[i] != target[k]) ++t;
            ++k;
        }
    }

    const T m = matches;
    return (m/sl + m/tl + 1 - t/m/2) / 3.0;
```

## A tiny typo

I'm guessing `boost_treshold` should be `boost_threshold`.

## Simplify the nested `min()` calls

If we change the type of `prefix` to match `source.length()` and `target.length()`, we can use the version of `std::min()` that accepts an initializer list:

```
        const auto l = std::min({source.length(), target.length(), prefix});
```

---

## My version

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>
#include <string_view>
#include <type_traits>

namespace edit_distance {
    template <typename T = double>
    inline std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, T>
    jaro_similarity(const std::string_view source,
                    const std::string_view target)
    {
        if (source == target)
            return 1;
        if (source.empty() || target.empty())
            return 0;

        const auto sl = source.length();
        const auto tl = target.length();

        const auto match_distance = std::max(sl, tl) < 2
                                    ? 0
                                    : std::max(sl, tl) / 2 - 1;

        auto source_matches = std::make_unique<bool[]>(sl);
        auto target_matches = std::make_unique<bool[]>(tl);
        std::size_t matches = 0;
        for (std::size_t i = 0;  i < sl;  ++i) {
            const auto end = std::min(i + match_distance + 1, tl);
            const auto start = i > match_distance ? (i - match_distance) : 0u;
            for (auto k = start;  k < end;  ++k) {
                if (!target_matches[k] && source[i] == target[k]) {
                    target_matches[k] = source_matches[i] = true;
                    ++matches;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (matches == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        std::size_t t = 0;
        for (std::size_t i = 0, k = 0;  i < sl;  ++i) {
            if (source_matches[i]) {
                while (!target_matches[k]) ++k;
                if (source[i] != target[k]) ++t;
                ++k;
            }
        }

        const T m = matches;
        return (m/sl + m/tl + 1 - t/m/2) / 3.0;
    }

    template <typename T = double>
    inline T jaro_winkler_similarity(const std::string_view source,
                                     const std::string_view target,
                                     const std::size_t prefix = 2,
                                     const T boost_treshold = 0.7,
                                     const T scaling_factor = 0.1)
    {
        const auto similarity = jaro_similarity<T>(source, target);

        if (similarity > boost_treshold) {
            const auto l = std::min({source.length(), target.length(), prefix});
            std::size_t common_prefix = 0;
            for (; common_prefix < l; ++common_prefix) {
                if (source[common_prefix] != target[common_prefix]) break;
            }
            return similarity
                 + scaling_factor * common_prefix * (1 - similarity);
        } else {
            return similarity;
        }
    }
} // namespace edit_distance



// Test program

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

static void show_distance(std::string_view a, std::string_view b)
{
    std::cout << "Similarity for '" << a
              << "' and '" << b
              << "': " << edit_distance::jaro_winkler_similarity(a, b)
              << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    show_distance(std::string{"DWAYNE"}, "DUANE");
    show_distance("MARTHA", "MARHTA");
    show_distance("DIXON", "DICKSONX");
    show_distance("JELLYFISH", "SMELLYFISH");
}
```

Comment: About the redundant test bit: Can you take a look at this broken-out example? https://godbolt.org/g/9V7RsK

Comment: I was wrong on that point - I've edited to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The other reviews have hit most of the points I'd have made, so this is a complementary review that looks primarily at the actual algorithm and testing.  I went to the source, [a 2006 paper by Winkler](https://www.census.gov/srd/papers/pdf/rrs2006-02.pdf) and extracted test vectors from a table on page 12.

I wanted to automate the testing in the simplest way possible (because I'm lazy!) and so I used this test harness.

### main.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
#include "jaro_winkler.hpp"
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

float jw(const std::string_view a, const std::string_view b) {
    return edit_distance::jaro_winkler(a, b, 4, 0.78, 0.1);
}

int main() {
    bool passed{true};
    for (const auto &t: tests) {
        passed &= t(jw);
    }
    std::cout << "\nAll tests " 
        << (passed ? "passed" : "did NOT pass!")
        << '\n';
}
```

### test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

class Test {
public:
    Test(const std::string &a, const std::string &b, float expected);
    bool operator()(float (&func)(const std::string_view a, 
                                  const std::string_view b)) const;
private:
    std::string a, b;
    float expected;
};

extern const std::vector<Test> tests;
#endif // TEST_H
```

### test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

Test::Test(const std::string &a, const std::string &b, float expected) :
    a{a}, b{b}, expected{expected}
{ }

bool Test::operator()(float (&func)(const std::string_view a, const std::string_view b)) const {
    constexpr float epsilon{0.0005};
    const auto dist{func(a, b)};
    const auto delta{std::abs(dist - expected)};
    const auto result{epsilon > delta};
    std::cout << std::setw(7) << std::boolalpha << result
            << std::setw(15) << a 
            << std::setw(15) << b 
            << '\t' << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << dist
            << '\t' << std::setprecision(4) << delta
            << '\n';
    return result;
}

/* 
 * These sample values are from
 * "Overview of Record Linkage and Current Research Directions"
 * Winkler, W. (2006)
 * https://www.census.gov/srd/papers/pdf/rrs2006-02.pdf
 */
const std::vector<Test> tests{
    { "SHACKLEFORD",    "SHACKELFORD",  0.982 },
    { "DUNNINGHAM",     "CUNNIGHAM",    0.896 },
    { "NICHLESON",      "NICHULSON",    0.956 },
    { "JONES",          "JOHNSON",      0.832 },
    { "MASSEY",         "MASSIE",       0.933 },
    { "ABROMS",         "ABRAMS",       0.922 },
    { "HARDIN",         "MARTINEZ",     0.000 },
    { "ITMAN",          "SMITH",        0.000 },

    { "JERALDINE",      "GERALDINE",    0.926 },
    { "MARHTA",         "MARTHA",       0.961 },
    { "MICHELLE",       "MICHAEL",      0.921 },
    { "JULIES",         "JULIUS",       0.933 },
    { "TANYA",          "TONYA",        0.880 },
    { "DWAYNE",         "DUANE",        0.840 },
    { "SEAN",           "SUSAN",        0.805 },
    { "JON",            "JOHN",         0.933 },
    { "JON",            "JAN",          0.000 },

};
```

## Results

When compiled and linked with your original code (and with the given parameters as shown in `main`) I found *almost* perfect agreement.  The only difference was apparently that while values above the threshold are boosted (as in your code), values below are clamped to 0.  I made the appropriate change to the code and the result is that all values match:

```
   true    SHACKLEFORD    SHACKELFORD   0.982   0.0002
   true     DUNNINGHAM      CUNNIGHAM   0.896   0.0003
   true      NICHLESON      NICHULSON   0.956   0.0004
   true          JONES        JOHNSON   0.832   0.0004
   true         MASSEY         MASSIE   0.933   0.0003
   true         ABROMS         ABRAMS   0.922   0.0002
   true         HARDIN       MARTINEZ   0.000   0.0000
   true          ITMAN          SMITH   0.000   0.0000
   true      JERALDINE      GERALDINE   0.926   0.0001
   true         MARHTA         MARTHA   0.961   0.0001
   true       MICHELLE        MICHAEL   0.921   0.0004
   true         JULIES         JULIUS   0.933   0.0003
   true          TANYA          TONYA   0.880   0.0000
   true         DWAYNE          DUANE   0.840   0.0000
   true           SEAN          SUSAN   0.805   0.0000
   true            JON           JOHN   0.933   0.0003
   true            JON            JAN   0.000   0.0000

All tests passed
```